# Continuity topological proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

I just want to see if I'm on the right track.  I've been struggling with this question for several days now, so I could really use help on it, as I have really given a concerted amount of time to think about it.

Since, I know that f is continuous, I know that pre-images of open sets in R are open in the rectangle defined by [0,1] x [0,1].  Now, I want to prove that g(x)=max{f(x,y)) is continuous on [0,1].  The main problem, I think I'm having is I don't understand what: [image] represents.  I want to take open sets and show that their pre-images are open in order to show that g(x) is continuous.  However, I'm not sure how to formalize this or how to construct an argument showing this.  Perhaps, using the definition of continuity using sequences would be better?  I have tried looking at similar examples but I don't find them too much.  I would be really grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $f$ is continuous on the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$, it is uniformly continuous. So there corresponds a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $(x,y),(a,b)\in [0,1]\times [0,1]$, $\lvert x - a\rvert < \delta$ and $\lvert y - b \rvert <\delta$ implies $\lvert f(x,y) - f(a,b)\rvert < \epsilon$. Given $x,a\in [0,1]$ with $\lvert x - a\rvert < \delta$, choose $y,z\in [0,1]$ such that $g(x) < f(x,y) + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $g(a) < f(a,z) + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Then $g(x) - g(a) < f(x,y) - f(a,y) + \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$ and similarly $g(a) - g(x) < f(a,z) - f(x,z) + \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon$. Thus $\lvert g(x) - g(a)\rvert < \epsilon$ whenever $\lvert x - a\rvert < \delta$. So $g$ is continuous.